# Dollar Sign in Variables

Tags: linux, bash

Dears, 
Can someone explain the reason for output 5 when i echo $15 . 
If 15 variable is not defined then there should be no output as in the second example

```
-bash-4.2$ echo $15
5
-bash-4.2$ echo ${15}

-bash-4.2$ echo $USER
kony
-bash-4.2$
-bash-4.2$ echo ${USER}
kony
```

Comment: `$15` is, for somewhat obscure reasons (hint: backward compatibility) treated as a reference to the first parameter (`$1`) followed by a totally unrelated “5” character. It’s equivalent to `${1}5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dollar sign is reserved, specifically $0, $1 etc for taking on arguments. You need to escape the dollar sign to print the value or put it in single quotes.

Try either of these:

```
echo \$15
echo '$15'
```

There will always be an output for your command because you are effectively saying "echo 5" Since there is no value for `$1` it is being ignored. $0 - $9 are all reserved by the system to reference arguments.  `echo $90` would return 0. etc.

[Reference](https://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/90037-what-1-a.html)